# How to use ListBox.Items as Itemsource of a List<String>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

I have a `ListBox`. I also have a `list` in code behind. I want to get all the items from the `listbox` as the source of my `list`.

I tried this way:

`<listBox x:Name="MyList" .../>`

```
list<string> feed = new list<string>();

//to get the source
var feed = MyList.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

but It's throwing an Exception: `System.InvalidCastException`

what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because your list isn't made of strings! Try to get the string representation instead.

```
List<string> feed = MyList.Items.Cast<object>()
    .Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list<T> feed = new list<T>();
var feed = MyList.Items.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

This is the correct way. But, see the type of items you have in your ListBox. They may not be `string` type That's why you are getting this error. You may not have items with the type `string`. Replace **T** with that type in your ListBox. Or fix your ListBox to have items with the type `string`.

Answer (score 2):

I think Sam's answer is correct. If the ItemsSource of your ListBox is string collection, then casting them to string should not be a problem.

```
        MyList.ItemsSource = new List<string>
        {
            "one","two","three"
        };
        List<string> feed = MyList.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

But if the ItemsSource of your ListBox is other than string collection, suppose MyClass collection

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.MyProperty;
        }
    }
```

Then you have to cast it in appropriate type and select desired property.

```
        MyList.ItemsSource = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass {MyProperty ="one"},
            new MyClass {MyProperty ="two"},
            new MyClass {MyProperty ="three"},
        };
        List<string> feed = MyList.Items.Cast<MyClass>().Select(c => c.MyProperty).ToList();
```

But to answer your question correctly we need to know about the ItemsSource of your ListBox.

Answer (score -1):

You know in wpf you have Listbox has ListboxItem and you have to cash you item to ListboxItem first.
And after that. You push the listboxItem.Content to your 
`List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in this.MyList.Items)
            {
                ListBoxItem castItem = item as ListBoxItem;
                list.Add(castItem.Content.ToString());
            }`

Here you can try